# Replacing HTML script tags manually after Grunt Build tools minify and concat to one file?

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs

Using Grunt scripts to build the development files into a distribution folder. During development, I have multiple different JS files I edit and import to the HTML files. After Grunt build, they are uglified and put into one JS file.

However, when I do this to build the dist folder, i then have to go to the HTML files and replace the script links with the one single link.

I could have it defaulted to the one single link, but for it to work, I have to rebuild the project every single save.

Is this normal? I feel like manually changing them isn't the way its suppose to be done, can scripts fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your concat task with [`grunt-concat-blocks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-concat-blocks), it allows you specify the files to concat on the html it self, so as a side effect, it also changes the list to the concated file, like you requested :].

```
<!-- build:js scripts/combined.concat.min.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/b.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

will become:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/combined.concat.min.js"></script>
```